# Cannot buy stockpile items anymore – even if they are available!

Tags: assassins-creed-3

It really pisses me off!

I was just playing “Assassin’s Creed 3” up to **sequence 9**. Right now, I am exploring the map and making money by buying pelts from Myriam and selling them via a land or naval convoy. In the meantime, I am trying to produce as many goods as possible. But there seems to be a certain point, where there is some kind of horrible bug in the game.

So, I was trying to buy some new pelts from Myriam or sand from Norris, but I just couldn’t buy it. For example, there were 7 sand available, that is it said 0/7. I filled it up to 7/7 and pressed enter, but no sand was added to my inventory and it still said 0/7! However, the amount of money was subtracted! Same for bear pelts and some other stuff!

What is that?! That problem now occurs for the seconed time, after I have reinstalled “Assassin’s Creed 3” and played the game **again** – right from the **beginning**!

I don’t know how to deal with that problem or if there is any solution to it. I just found some sites, where the same problem is described, but there is no solution to it. Here is an example:

- http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/621796-assassins-creed-iii/answers/352235-i-cannot-buy-items-in-stockpile-even-if-there

So, maybe I can find a solution here.

I know that there are some suggestions on how to solve that problem, but nothing works for me. Reducing my items below the amount of 1500 does not work, as well as accomplishing some missions. Also, many people do not seem to understand the question properly. That’s why I am posting this here, hoping to finally get a **working** solution.

Comment: By the way: That was the source, saying that only 1500 items may be allowed, which I do not consider to be true: http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/621797-assassins-creed-iii/answers/344679-why-cant-i-purchase-stockpile-goods-anymore

Comment: Why even put up with this? The convoy interface is the most horrible UI ever conceived (if i recall correctly something like 200 keypresses to send out a single convoy) and the money it generates isn't needed at all. At least, when I played, I made exactly one convoy the entire game, then I never touched that interface again and still could easily buy everything. I don't have an answer, I can just tell you to forget this terrible part of the game and move on.

Comment: Well, but this “terrible part of the game” is needed in order to accomplish the 100%, because you need to deliver some stuff to people you do not easily get. So, you have to produce it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer and you will not like it.

IT IS A GLITCH. I call it the OCD/Hoarder Glitch.

I was trying to craft all items (without shipping off for money) and figured out the issue.

SOURCE OF GLITCH: when you do assassin missions and you received item as a reward for completion — if you currently have a 10/10 stockpile of that item the game glitches and thinks you have 11 so you cannot buy more despite stockpile refilling.

If you have 10/10 iron and mission rewards iron it glitches.

For example:

Iron ore (this was the case for me, most unfortunate as it is important for many items)

Stockpile showing: 10/10 available for purchase

You can add resources in menu where you add quantity and purchase and even after you do stockpile will remain 10 and inventory will remain 0.

If it shows 10 Available and You have 0 its over for you. However i managed to un glitch other items buy buying lets say 2 instead of 9

So

I have 10 and got an 11th, so i crafted 9 and would have been left with 2 despite it showing 1.

At this point (as i usually do) i hit max quantity (9) and try to buy but it wont add because i have 2 showing but really 1 and if it let me purchace 9 i would be at 11 again so game just takes your money and gives you nothing.

Heres the trick.

Remember you have 2 its showing 1. So even tho its showing max purchase quantity of 9 if you select 8 or less it will work. You have to buy 2 at a time or 3 or 4 or 5 just not 9. I recommend 2

But if you get to 10 available for purchase and 0 available for crafting you are FUCKED.

If you stumble across this before encountering the problem i highly suggest upu keep a maximum of 6-7 of an item no more at any time.

U don’t need 10 apples guys. 6 are fine.